# NSArrayI rangeOfCharacterFrom set error

Tags: ios, objective-c, sigabrt

I am receiving a Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT. And it is not pointing out on which line it is throwing the error. Anyway, here is the error log

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI rangeOfCharacterFromSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdabc0d7d10'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c55bf45 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010b849deb objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c56456d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c4b1eea ___forwarding___ + 970
4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c4b1a98 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   UIKit                               0x000000010a1392e8 -[UILabel _contentInsetsFromFonts] + 137
6   UIKit                               0x000000010a4519d2 -[_UILabelLayer updateContentInsets] + 127
7   UIKit                               0x000000010a451ac1 -[_UILabelLayer updateContentLayerSize] + 50
8   UIKit                               0x000000010a451c2f -[_UILabelLayer layoutSublayers] + 25
9   QuartzCore                          0x0000000108ef8e70 
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

And here's the method that It is using

```
{
NSArray *contentArray = [dictionary objectForKey:@"info"];
NSString *holder;
holder=[[contentArray valueForKey:@"title"] uppercaseString];
if(holder)
{
    self.titleLabel.text =  holder;
}
else
{
    self.titleLabel.text =  MJEmptyString;
}

holder = [contentArray valueForKey:@"synopsis"];
if(holder)
{
    self.descriptionText.text = holder;
}
else
{
    self.descriptionText.text = MJEmptyString;
}

NSString *starcastList;
NSString *directorList;

contentArray = [dictionary objectForKey:@"people"];
for(NSDictionary *contentDict in contentArray)
{
    if([contentDict[@"type"]isEqual:@"Director"])
    {
        directorList = contentDict[@"fullName"];
        continue;
    }
    if([contentDict[@"type"]isEqual:@"Actor"])
    {
        starcastList = contentDict[@"fullName"];
        continue;
    }
}

if(starcastList)
{
    self.starcastLabel.text = [starcastList capitalizedString];
}
else
{
    self.starcastLabel.text = MJEmptyString;
}
if(directorList)
{
    self.directorLabel.text = [directorList capitalizedString];

}
else
{
    self.directorLabel.text = MJEmptyString;
}
self.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:0.0f/255.0f blue:51.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
self.starcastLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:0.0f/255.0f blue:51.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
self.directorLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:0.0f/255.0f blue:51.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
self.descriptionText.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:0.0f/255.0f blue:51.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];

NSMutableAttributedString *title = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Starring : %@",starcastList]];
//[title addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:UIColorFromRGB(0x000000)range:NSMakeRange(0, 10)];
self.starcastLabel.attributedText = title;

title = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Director : %@",directorList]];
//[title addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:UIColorFromRGB(0x000000) range:NSMakeRange(0, 10)];
self.directorLabel.attributedText = title;

NSString *formatOfYear;
#if DEVELOPMENT_SERVER
formatOfYear = @"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss";
#else
formatOfYear =@"dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss a";
#endif

NSLog(@"%@",formatOfYear);
NSDate *releaseDate = [MJUtilities getDateFromString:dictionary[@"originalRelease"] format:formatOfYear];
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSDate *emptyDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];
if([df stringFromDate:releaseDate])
{
    self.yearOfRelease.text = [df stringFromDate:releaseDate];
}
else
{
    self.yearOfRelease.text =[df stringFromDate:emptyDate];

}
NSArray *timeComponents = [dictionary[@"runtime"] componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
NSInteger hours = 0;
NSInteger minutes = 0;
if(timeComponents && timeComponents.count >= 2)
{
     hours = [timeComponents[0] integerValue];
     minutes = [timeComponents[1] integerValue];
}

NSInteger totaltime = (hours*60) + minutes;
if([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld min",(long)totaltime])
{
    self.runningTime.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld min",(long)totaltime];
}
else
{
    self.runningTime.text = MJEmptyString;
}
if([contentArray valueForKey:@"rating"])
{
    self.contentRating.text = [contentArray valueForKey:@"rating"];
}
else
{
    self.contentRating.text = MJEmptyString;
}

  //  CGFloat movieAverageRating =[@"2.5" stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"."] floatValue];
CGFloat movieAverageRating =[@"2.5" floatValue];;
self.movieRatingView.maxRating = 5;
self.movieRatingView.imageSize = CGSizeMake(20, 20);
self.movieRatingView.imageSpacing = 10;
if([MJDeviceUtilities isDevicePhone])
{
    self.movieRatingView.imageSize = CGSizeMake(16 , 16);
    self.movieRatingView.imageSpacing = 5;
}
self.movieRatingView.fullRatingImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star_red.png"];
self.movieRatingView.halfRatingImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star_02.png"];
self.movieRatingView.noRatingImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star_gray.png"];
self.movieRatingView.rating = movieAverageRating;
self.currentRating = movieAverageRating;

self.numberOfRatings = [@"2" intValue];   // [dictionary[@"NoOfConsumerRatings"] integerValue];


NSLog(@"Number of ratings %ld",[dictionary[@"NoOfConsumerRatings"] integerValue]);

[self.scrollView fadeFromAplha:self.scrollView.alpha toAlpha:OPAQUE_ALPHA duration:MJFastAnimDuration];
self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
self.descriptionText.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0); 


[self resetLabelFrames];

CGFloat contentSizeHeight = self.relatedMoviesView.frame.origin.y + CGRectGetHeight(self.relatedMoviesView.frame);
UIInterfaceOrientation statusBarOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

if ([MJDeviceUtilities isDevicePad] && UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(statusBarOrientation))
{
    contentSizeHeight = contentSizeHeight + 15.0f;
}
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.scrollView.frame), contentSizeHeight);

// self.screenTitle = self.movieContentType;
self.screenTitle = MJEmptyString;
}
```

I am sure that every holder or every UIObject has values. And I really don't know why am I receiving an error.

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@",[contentArray valueForKey:@"title"] );` and check what you are getting

Comment: Maybe the *KVC-trap*. `valueForKey` applied to an array returns always an array.

Comment: @MidhunMP Yeah, did that. I am getting the right values that I need

Comment: The value of the [contentArray valueForKey:@"title] is Test Title 1. Which is correct. So I don't think it is the "KVC-trap" @vadian

Comment: But the error message points to that issue. Somewhere a string is expected but an array is passed.

Comment: So I can't do something like self.label.text = [array valueForKey@"key"]; cause it will return an array? Am I getting it right?

Comment: @vadian Tried to put all valueForKey that I need in an NSString before I set it to the label.text. Still having the same error.

Comment: What is the purpose of `valueForKey` in your case? An array is an **index**-based collection type unlike a dictionary which is **key**-based.

Comment: Cause my array is dynamic. It returns key/value in different index everytime @vadian